# android the bottom of the scrollview disappear

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I am making an android app with scrollview and inside the scrollview there is a relativelayout and both of them have a background and it works fine but when I try to make space between the scrollview and the relativelayout by using marginTop and Bottom, the bottom of the scrollview disappear.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"

    >

 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="730dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg2"

        >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp" />


  </RelativeLayout>       

   </ScrollView>
```

when I run the app I want this:

[image]

but I am getting this, I cant view the bottom:

[image]

Comment: remove `android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"` from `RelativeLayout` and check it.. Use only `marginTop`

Comment: Can you show us what you're getting and what you want ?

Comment: I added what I  am getting and what I want in the question

Comment: why are you using `hardcoded` values? If you do so then your layout doesn't fit in all the screens. In your XML there are only 3 buttons, how are you getting 7 buttons when you run it?

Comment: I have many buttons but I put 3 for example

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your Scroll View:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

and in RelativeLayout:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add this line into your `<ScrollView></ScrollView>` Tag in view's XML File.

```
android:padding="15dp"
```

It will solve your problem.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work I also tried paddingBottom and top

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#15375e"

    >

 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:background="#000000"

        >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="1" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_height="40dp" 
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="3"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:text="4" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_height="40dp" 
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="6"/>


  </RelativeLayout>       

   </ScrollView>
```

If you use this above code, you will get output like [image: this]. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Why you cannot add more than six buttons?. You can add as many buttons as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've just stumbled upon this issue and found a solution.

It seems that if you set the bottom margin for the layout inside the scrollview it doesn't behave as expected. As a solution, you can set the padding for that element instead of the margin. If you want a background that takes the whole screen you can set that on the scrollview itself.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <!--Your elements go here-->

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Hope this helps someone!